# Calling SignedCMS.Decode takes too long

Tags: c#, .net, digital-signature, pkcs#7

Is there any reason that calling SignedCMS.Decode would take 15 seconds or more?  I have the following code:

```
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms();
signedCms.Decode(postedData);
```

where postedData is a byte array of a signed CMS message.  Sometimes the function call returns instantly, but most of the time, it takes 10-15 seconds to return causing the message sender to timeout.

This seems to happen whether or not the debugger is attached to the process.

Comment: Are you using bouncy castle?

Comment: No.  Using .Net System.Security in c#

Comment: I'm asking because Bouncy / Java has a lot of initialization happening - this is only present at startup. Maybe it is the same for `System.Security`? Easy to test, just run CMS decode multiple times and see when the delay happens.

Comment: Well it's definitely not when the object is constructed, only when .Decode is called.  I tried calling it two times after the initial and it still takes a long time.  Funny thing is that sometimes it returns quickly and it only seems to be happening on one machine.

Answer (score 1):

So I narrowed it down to an instantiation of Oid in one of the functions that the Decode function calls.  The source is available at [Reference Source .NET Framework 4.5.1](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security).

I tested using:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Oid oid = new System.Security.Cryptography.Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1");
```

I also found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e6cd018-7574-4a58-97a0-a74f66a384e3/systemsecuritycryptographyoid-changed-behavior-in-net-40?forum=clr) with a similar problem.

Interestingly, disconnecting my wireless adapter, the Oid instantiation occurs immediately, which leads me to believe that it may be network/DNS related (I have not idea what the Oid instantiation is doing).  After reconnecting my adapter SignedCms.Decode is working as normal.  Another option I read is to remove  my computer from the domain and then rejoin.  Haven't tried it yet.

Maybe this will help anyone else that is have the same (or similar) problem.

Comment: That's just CMS: http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.2.840.113549.1.7.1&action=display so that's not saying much. It's probably something to do with the key/certificate store blocking. As you are verifying it's probably not the random number generator (which can be waiting for entropy from the LAN connector). You could test the output of the default RNG, if it blocks it *may* still be the issue (as starting an RNG could be part of the overall security framework).